# JQuery sortable bind a click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

How can I bind a click event on a specific item in [sortable of `jQuery UI`](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/)?

```
<div id="sortable"></div>`
```

I tried using

```
$(document).on('click', '#sortable', function() { 
     alert('test'); 
});
```

But when I click one item, It clicks everything. Is there a way to know which item is clicked?

**update:**

Thanks for noticing my typing error now removed the quotation in the document. And here is a fiddle.

I created [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4hkP2/) for you guys.

To reproduce: drag 2 items on to the main then click the item

Comment: @mplungjan drag 2 items on to the main then click the item

Comment: Ok, and what is expected behaviour? Please read http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click', '#sortable', function(e) { 
     alert(e.target); // here you will see for more detail use **console** 
});
```

reference **[event.target](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/)**

Comment: remove quotes from document

Comment: @Riturajratan please see my fiddle

Answer (score 0):

You have typo

Remove quotes from document

```
$(document).on('click', '#sortable', function(event) { 
   alert(event.target.nodeName);
});
```

---

References

[event.target](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/)

Comment: @user2785929 what is the problem with fiddle ?

Comment: The alert trigger twice.

Comment: @user2785929 because you are using label to focus on the element.When u click on label it trigger's focus event for element in `for` attribute.Chek Update to solve the issue --> http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/4hkP2/1/

Comment: Sorry for this noob response. I don't know how I can put a `popover` in the fiddle but I tried to put a `popover` to the event in my code  but It display more than one popover when clicked. Is there a way to fix this issue?

Comment: @user2785929 Use ` event.preventDefault();` in click event .Create a fiddle .

Comment: Yes I did that. But It seems that the radio button and the label triggers at the same time if i clicked it.

Comment: I updated it but the popover doesn't show up because there is no bootstrap plug in. Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/4hkP2/2/)  ok?